# How to use a variable as user name in a SF memory provider?

Tags: symfony, environment-variables

I was trying to use a variable provided by my `.env` file as the username in the memory provider in my `security.yml` file. My configuration looks like that:

```
security:
    providers:
        page:
            memory:
                users:
                    "%env(PAGE_USERNAME)%": { password: '%env(PAGE_PASSWORD)%' }
```

It was working recently but now I've got an exception every time I am using the console. Here is the exception:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvParameterException]                                                                
A service name ("security.user.provider.concrete.page_%env(PAGE_USERNAME)%") cannot contain dynamic values.
```

After some research, it turns out that there was a [modification](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/24673) in `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckDefinitionValidityPass` recently which changed that behavior.

Is there another way of doing what I want to do?
Is this considered as a bug?

Comment: I had the problem in another yml file, it seems it is not allowed now. It isn't a bug for sure.

Answer (score 0):

For me this work perfectly ! ;)

```html
    providers:
        authorized_users:
            memory:
                users:
                    "%env(HTTP_BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME)%":
                        password: '%env(HTTP_BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD)%'
```